# How to generate sequences from a grammar in (pure) R?

Tags: r, code-generation, context-free-grammar, bnf, part-of-speech

I would like to generate a list of part of speech sequences from a (context-free) grammar written in Backus-Naur form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form).

I tested the package gramEvol and the functions 'CreateGrammar' and 'GrammarRandomExpression' but it is random, I would prefer a full list, and I suspect that it is possible to write a function more formally and more elegantly in pure R.

```
sequences <- GenerateSequencesFromBnf()
 
GenerateSequencesFromBnf <- function(){
  library(gramEvol)
  rules <- list(expr = gsrule("<det>.<adj>.<noun>.<core>"),
                core = gsrule("NOUN"),
                det = gsrule("", "DET"),
                adj = gsrule("", "ADJ", "<adj>.ADJ"),
                noun = gsrule("", "NOUN", "<noun>.NOUN")
                )
  grammar <- CreateGrammar(rules)
  sequences <- unique(unlist(GrammarRandomExpression(grammar, 10)))
  return(sequences)
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply.
I think it would be better to ask grammar questions on the [github page](https://github.com/fnoorian/gramEvol/issues) of the authors of the package

The package has the ability to call all possible expressions sequentially
Please use

`? gramEvol::GrammarGetNextSequence()`

```
library(gramEvol)
  rules <- list(expr = gsrule("<det>.<adj>.<noun>.<core>"),
                core = gsrule("NOUN"),
                det = gsrule("", "DET"),
                adj = gsrule("", "ADJ", "<adj>.ADJ"),
                noun = gsrule("", "NOUN", "<noun>.NOUN"))
  
  grammar <- CreateGrammar(rules)



 string <- NULL
  while (TRUE) {
    string <- GrammarGetNextSequence(grammar, string)
    if (is.GrammarOverflow(string)) break
    expr <- GrammarMap(string, grammar)
    cat(string, " -> ", as.character(expr), "\n")
  }
```

result is

```
0 0 0 0 0  ->  ...NOUN 
0 0 0 1 0  ->  ..NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 0 2 0 0  ->  ...NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 0 2 1 0  ->  ..NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 0 2 2 0 0  ->  ...NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 0 2 2 1 0  ->  ..NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0  ->  ...NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 0 2 2 2 1 0  ->  ..NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 0 0  ->  .ADJ..NOUN 
0 0 1 1 0  ->  .ADJ.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 2 0 0  ->  .ADJ..NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 2 1 0  ->  .ADJ.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 2 2 0 0  ->  .ADJ..NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 2 2 1 0  ->  .ADJ.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0  ->  .ADJ..NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 1 2 2 2 1 0  ->  .ADJ.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 2 0 0 0  ->  ..ADJ..NOUN 
0 0 2 0 1 0  ->  ..ADJ.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 2 0 2 0 0  ->  ..ADJ..NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 2 0 2 1 0  ->  ..ADJ.NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
0 0 2 0 2 2 0 0  ->  ..ADJ..NOUN.NOUN.NOUN 
......
....
..
.
```